# WIF 3.5 issue with infinite loop only on localhost domains

Tags: asp.net, wif

When I run my application on localhost the app goes into infinite loop upon authentication process, more specifically when token is issued from STS and received on RP and after that the request goes back to STS and this process repeats inifinitely.

My web.config of RP website:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="microsoft.identityModel" type="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Configuration.MicrosoftIdentityModelSection, Microsoft.IdentityModel, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
  </configSections>

  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
        <add name="WSFederationAuthenticationModule" type="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.WSFederationAuthenticationModule, Microsoft.IdentityModel, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" preCondition="managedHandler" />
        <add name="SessionAuthenticationModule" type="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.SessionAuthenticationModule, Microsoft.IdentityModel, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" preCondition="managedHandler" />
    </modules>
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
          <assemblies>
            <add assembly="Microsoft.IdentityModel, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
          </assemblies>
        </compilation>
        <httpModules>
          <add name="Session" type="System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule" />
          <add name="WSFederationAuthenticationModule" type="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.WSFederationAuthenticationModule, Microsoft.IdentityModel, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
          <add name="SessionAuthenticationModule" type="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.SessionAuthenticationModule, Microsoft.IdentityModel, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
        </httpModules>
        <microsoft.identityModel>
            <service>
                <certificateValidation certificateValidationMode="None" />

                <issuerNameRegistry type="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.ConfigurationBasedIssuerNameRegistry, Microsoft.IdentityModel, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35">
                    <trustedIssuers>
                      <add thumbprint="*VALUE*" name="CertficateName" />
                    </trustedIssuers>
                </issuerNameRegistry>

                <audienceUris>
                    <add value="http://localhost/RP/" />
                </audienceUris>

                <federatedAuthentication>
                    <wsFederation
                        issuer="http://localhost/STS/"
                        realm="http://localhost/RP/"
                        reply="http://localhost/RP/"
                        requireHttps="false"
                        persistentCookiesOnPassiveRedirects="true" />
                    <cookieHandler
                        mode="Default"
                        domain="localhost"
                        hideFromScript="false"
                        name="FedAuthCookie"
                        path="/RP/"
                        requireSsl="false"
                        persistentSessionLifetime="60.0:0:0" />
                </federatedAuthentication>
            </service>
        </microsoft.identityModel>
</configuration>
```

Strange thing that with exactly the same configuration the app works with domains like `http://test.com/RP` or `http://test.com/RP/`, but won't work with `http://localhost/RP` or `http://localhost/RP/`.

I have no errors neither in Event Viewer nor at runtime, token is issued by STS, but maybe for some reason it is not applied or accepted by RP.

Comment: Take a look in Fiddler what happens. My guess is that the FAM issues a cookie but for some reason SAM doesn't accept it or the cookie is missing at all. Is the cookie name the same in both RP and STS by chance?

Comment: Ok, I followed your advice and ran Fiddler2 to compare "localhost" and "test.com" sessions. The authentication round-trip between STS and RP has 3 requests. The "localhost" session is missing "FedAuthCookie" on the third request to RP, although "test.com" has this cookie. Strange thing that it's not saved on the third request, although I have the "domain" and "path" properties explicitly set up on "cookieHandler" node. How can I preserve the "FedAuthCookie" on "localhost"?

Comment: Do both STS and RP create cookies with the same name? This won't work. Take a closer look what happens when the response carrying the SAML token from STS gets to RP. In the very next request, RP should issue its own cookie that retains user session. For some reason yours RP doesn't do that, or does it wrongly. Cookie name clash is just one of possible issues.

Comment: The first request sets WebForms authentication cookie on STS (not "FedAuthCookie" since STS should not have this cookie) and to goes to RP. The second request is a request for Security Token from RP to STS and here STS issues token from STS to RP and sends it, also this request contains "Set-Cookie" header. The third request creates token and I mark the token as to be stored in session (to reduce the size of the "FedAuthCookie"). So the "FedAuthCookie" must only be created on RP, am I right? There should be no collision with cookie names between STS and RP.

Comment: Usually, the first request is to RP and the response is 302 to STS. Second request is to STS and response is 200 and the STS shows the login page. Third request is a POST to STS (with username/pwd) and the response is 200 that contains: the STS cookie, the SAML token and a bit of javascript that submits the form back to RP. Fourth request is POST, the form being submited to RP, there is no cookie. The response is 200, token is parsed and the FedAuthCookie is issued by RP. The cookie contains the token so that the SAM module retains the session.

Comment: Ok, I have all these requests, I mentioned 3 last request just for the brevity. Well, thank you for your help, I will investigate further and I hope I'll resolve this issue.